# Winsock Program in c language is not working

Tags: c, sockets, mingw, winsock

I've started another program to run Winsock in C language on Windows7.

I found this help on msdn:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

This program is not working and showing these errors:

$ gcc ak1.c -o ak1.exe -lwsock32 -lws2_32 -lAdvapi32 -lmswsock

C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Temp\ccWqZC7C.o:ak1.c:(.text+0x109): undefined re
ference to `getaddrinfo'

C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Temp\ccWqZC7C.o:ak1.c:(.text+0x1fa): undefined re
ference to `freeaddrinfo'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\a
mit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccWqZC7C.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in section `.eh_frame'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link
 failed: Invalid operation

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Is this error related to MICROSOFT SDK for Windows7, means these libraries are not added on my system.
I checked "Advapi32" is not under my micrsoft SDK.

Help please !!!

Answer (score 0):

You're using GCC (presumably MinGW) which doesn't use Microsoft's SDK.  `getaddrinfo()` and `freeaddrinfo()` are declared in MinGW's `ws2tcpip.h` implementation, but only if WinXP or later is targeted.

Add `-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501` to your compiler command line to target XP.

Comment: It is still not working, I would like to mention that I've done the following changes to run that program (as sys.h etc never run on windows, if the following changes are not done):

Comment: #ifdef WIN32
    #include <Winsock2.h>
    #include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#else
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <sys/un.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

Comment: All I know is that using MinGW 4.7.2 and the command line you posted, when I compile the program on the MSDN website you pointed to I get the same undefined reference errors (however I don't get the bad reloc address error).  When I add `-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501` to the compile command, I get no linker errors. The appropriate `_WIN32_WINNT` configuration is shown to be necessary by looking at the MinGW `ws2tcpip.h` header. You may need to reinstall MinGW and/or make sure there are no environment variables that are causing the compiler to pickup the wrong headers or libraries.

Comment: ok sir, what should I add as under 1st and 2nd command line argument...and how to use command line in mingw, I tried this ------> $ gcc ak1.c 127.0.0.1 -o ak1.exe -lwsock32 -lws2_32 -lAdvapi32 -lmswsock......here 127.0.0.1 is command line i.e argv[1] (I think so)...help me and correct if I'm wrong

Comment: `gcc` only compiles the program - it doesn't run it and has nothing to do with the arguments passed to it.  Compile the program using `gcc -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 ak1.c -o ak1 -lwsock32 -lws2_32 -ladvapi32 -lmswsock` then run it using `ak1 127.0.0.1`.  Of course, you'll need to have the server program from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737593.aspx compiled and running for the `ak1 127.0.0.1` command to actually do anything noteworthy.

Answer (score -2):

the solution is to add *"-lws2_32"* at the end of the command to compile with gcc ;-)